# How can I build a 2 input AND gate 24VDC PNP inputs and 24VDC output?

Tags: digital-logic, diodes

I'm trying to build an AND gate that takes two inputs from standard 3 wire 24VDC PNP sensors and provides a 24VDC output.

I was thinking using some sort of diode resistor logic (link to circuit: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/diodgate.html).  However, I can't get this to work because when the sensors are off, the output of the sensor does not pull the inputs of the gate to ground.

What is the best / simplest way to to this?

Comment: No pull to ground = RTL.

Comment: Can't you just add pulldowns?

Comment: I tried to simulate with a pull-down but it doesn't seem to work: <http://www.partsim.com/simulator/#33536>

Comment: What kind of an output is required? PNP also? or NPN?

Comment: The output should be PNP.

Comment: In your simulation, both circuits are 'powered' - the PNP is effectively on, so the output is high as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, it could be that you could get away with simply using a very low pull down and a relatively high pullup, but the below will definitely work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRADp7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: One issue I have is I have a very small amount of room for the circuit so it would be nice to simply be able to add a pull down resistor.  However, when I simulated this, it did not seem to work.

Comment: Your sim used a high pull down compared to pullup. It has to be opposite, but it may not be reliable.